# Interpretation of cointegrating equation

Tags: interpretation, cointegration

I have big and positive coefficients, so I don't know if it's correct and if it's a problem. I did the Engle-Granger test and found cointegration and did Johansen and found cointegration too.

[image]

Comment: These number are not impossible. Without further context, it is hard to say more.

Comment: @RichardHardyI am doing a VEC model between gross debt, interest rate, exchange rate, and GDP. I did the engle granger test and found cointegration when GDP was the dependent variable and I did the Johansen test and found one cointegration.

gdp (-0.010194), interest rate (4.289137), gross debt (2.620191) and exchange rate (0.330566)